# Vue.js Axios get value from local storage (localforage) returns promise object instead of value

Tags: javascript, local-storage, vuejs2, axios, localforage

I am trying to get a value from [`localforage`](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) for an [`axios`](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) call, but it is not working.

```
axios.get('https://api.example.org/api/?uname=' + this.$getItem('LSuname'), {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.$getItem('LSmytoken')}
})
```

I'm getting a 403 error with this in the console:

> XHR failed loading: GET "https://api.example.org/api/?uname=[object%20Promise]".

I have also tried `this.$getItem('LSuname').then(value => { return value })` and `this.$getItem('LSuname').then(function (value) { return value })` but I get the same exact 403 and bad url with a promise at the end

I am able to correctly return the value without issue elsewhere in my vue like so:

```
this.$getItem('LSuname').then(value => {
  console.log('uname:' + value)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `this.$getItem` is an asynchronous call that will return a `Promise`. This means you have to wait for that call to finish before calling any code which depends on the returned values of those async calls.

In your case, you could use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all of the async calls to return before making the `axios.get` call:

```
let unamePromise = this.$getItem('LSuname');
let mytokenPromise = this.$getItem('LSmytoken');

Promise.all([unamePromise, mytokenPromise]).then((vals) => {
  axios.get('https://api.example.org/api/?uname=' + vals[0], {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + vals[1] }
  })
})
```

Comment: in a similar vein (perhaps?) I can't get a simple value from local storage to just display on my page, any pointers? (I have tried setting it as a computed value, a method, trying to add something like `fullname: this.$getItem('LSfullname')` to the data, but nothing works.

Comment: Like I said, `this.$getItem()` is always going to return a Promise. If you set `fullname` equal to `this.$getItem('LSfullname')`, then `fullname` will be the Promise, not the result of the asynchronous function. You can read up on Promises here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

Comment: I tried to use the same Promise.all syntax above to return the value but it too failed. And there doesn't seem to be a way to get a value out of the localstorage directly. I will read up, thanks for the link.